# Cannot save object to Python multiprocessing shared dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below (self contained example) code passes a list of objects to a function in parallel using multiprocessing. There is a global multiprocessing manager and i'd like the function to store each object in the global dictionary.

However, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MyObj' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
"""The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 37, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 367, in map
return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
ERROR!
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 774, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.managers.RemoteError:
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Self-contained example code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

manager = mp.Manager()
dictionary = manager.dict()

class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = 0

def task(lock, obj):
    
    lock.acquire()
    dictionary["test"] = obj       # Trying to copy object to shared dictionary
    lock.release()

def task_init(output_queue):
    task.output_queue = output_queue


my_list = []

obj = MyObj("")
my_list.append(obj)

    
output_queue = mp.Queue()

p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count(), task_init, [output_queue])

lock = manager.Lock()
func = partial(task, lock)

p.map(func, my_list)
p.close()

print("finished")
```

Comment: You have not followed the rule about putting all of your one-time initialization code in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` fence.  There is a very good reason for requiring that.  That may not be the direct cause here, but it's a contributor.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you very much. Please put as an answer and i will accept.

Comment: Exactly how are you executing this?  I'm struck by the first line of the traceback, where it says `File "<string>"`.  And isn't each process going to overwrite the single entry in your dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I rearrange the code to put all the one-time initialization inside a `__main__` fence, this seems to work as expected.  This runs the task three times, but of course only saves one result:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from functools import partial

class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = 0

def task(lock, obj):
    
    lock.acquire()
    dictionary["test"] = obj       # Trying to copy object to shared dictionary
    lock.release()

def task_init(output_queue):
    task.output_queue = output_queue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = mp.Manager()
    dictionary = manager.dict()

    my_list = []

    my_list.append(MyObj(""))
    my_list.append(MyObj(""))
    my_list.append(MyObj(""))
   
    output_queue = mp.Queue()

    p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count(), task_init, [output_queue])

    lock = manager.Lock()
    func = partial(task, lock)

    p.map(func, my_list)
    p.close()

    print("finished")
    print(dictionary)
```